# Youtube-v3-Api PlayListItems: list - video that is in the list is not returned when filtered by video id

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use  PlaylistItems: list (method) in my java code.

The code itself is irrelevant here as the problem can be replicated with use of Youtube API examples here

**https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list**

**The problem:**

While video with specific id exists in the playList,
when using list query on playlistlist **filtered by video id** and **maxResults < of the vieo's sequence number**, the result returned is an **empty list** instead of list with that specific video.

**For example:**

**https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list**

```
  part  = snippet,id
    
     playlistId = PL6894BC5B5D452193
    
     videoId    = xEsC1tw-pOw  
    
     maxResults = 5 (default value) 

 (the 11th video in litst)
```

**Result is empty list.**

But if i search for

```
part  = snippet,id

playlistId = PL6894BC5B5D452193

videoId    = m1V1SjMD1lo
```

**video is found**
(the 1st video in list)

As far as I can tell the reason is the value of
maxResults parameter.

However in a real world scenario - my list contains more that 100 items and the max allowed value for maxResults is 50.

So is there a way to find the correct video using **list** method?

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are correct. You should open an issue at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:API-YouTube

Comment: @johnh10 Thanks for your reply. I followed your advice and opened an issue...let's see what happens next ;-)

Comment: The URL of the issue is [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7734&q=label%3AAPI-YouTube&sort=-id&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) . No answer yet...